# Matlab server Program Error

Tags: sockets, matlab

I am new to Matlab environment

I tried to implenment the Matlab sockets server using the existing java server sockets code
here is the code of Matlab server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

    try 
        providerSocket = ServerSocket(4443, 10);

        System.out.println('Waiting for connection');
        connection = providerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println('Connection received from ');

        out =  ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in =  ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        sendMessage('Connection successful');

    catch ME
```

Here is the error i got when executed in matlab...

```
    error(ME.identifier, 'Connection Error: %s', ME.message)
    end


Connection Error: Java exception occurred:
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets
error: 0: JVM_Bind

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)

at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)

at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)

at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you 
Please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that some other socket is blocking port 4443. If using a different port works, then that was the problem. Get the [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals) tools to see what ports are open - in particular, [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437).